# Gathering test result data in Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I am working on gathering test results. I am using Pytest (version 5.1.0).

Specifically, I need the following data after all tests are done running:

- Name of the test
- Test duration
- Stack trace (if any)
- Outcome / Status of the test

I see that I can get most of data using the following:

`def pytest_collectreport(report)`

But it appears I cannot get the test duration and stack trace using `report` object in the above hook.

Any idea how can I access all above-mentioned data related to all tests? Thanks for all help in advance.